# <img src: <call and then call again>/>

Tags: html

Hei there!
I have a bunch of images in a google bucket, identified by id's
I also have a rest API that can be called with an id query parameter like so

```
GET: /give_image_pls?id=619e0dd124122some10190cdbdb9
RESPONSE: https://storage.googleapis.com/619e0dd12412210190cdbdb9.png
```

This is because the server creates a URL that's valid for a few seconds

Is there any way, **frontend** or **backend**, that I could do

```
<html>
  <img src=/give_image_pls?id=619e0dd12412210190cdbdb9/>
</html>
```

in such a way that the `src` property would request the URL and then request the response URL to finally display the image?

I have tried setting `30[0..9]` status codes in the `give_image_pls` response, that did not do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server should return a [`302 Found` response code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_redirection) with the new URL in the [`Location` HTTP response header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location); this way the browser will transparently make another request to that URL.

Comment: Thanks buddy! `res.set('Location', url);` worked like a charm